# How i can create Mobile Application (Android,IOS,Blockberry) using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

i am a web developer.i want to create a mobile application for android and Ios using angularJS. The application is like a facebook app.which tool i can use this.and where i can start.anyone known please help me.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Hey, I think is better to re-think your question.
What do you want to do? To create an Android app?

Comment: You should search your favorite search engine for "How do I make cross-platform apps?" or "PhoneGap vs Titanium" or "Cross-platform android, apple, blackberry apps". Those will yield thousands of results.

Comment: sorry, if any chance is there for to develop a native app using android studio?

Comment: Please search for "convert native android app to ios". If you don't find something that satisfies your answer, then it doesn't exist, or it isn't reliable enough to be popular.

Comment: Thanks for u r answer..but i have edit this question pls help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are simple:

1. Use a cross platform app development framework, such as Titanium, PhoneGap, Xamarin, or whatever else you prefer. These offer various levels of code portability, and have their strengths and weaknesses. There are many articles written to contrast these, so go use a search engine.
2. If you want to use Android Studio, then write the app in Android Studio. But if you want an iOS app as well, then you'll need to write the app again in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for u r answer..but i have edit this question pls help me..

Answer (score 1):

*I also searching for not C++ but javascript in Android Studio. 
I found this sample.*

Teapot
Teapot is an Android C++ sample that draws a Teapot mesh using GLES 2.0 API and NativeActivity.

This sample uses the new Gradle Experimental Android plugin with C++ support.

Pre-requisites

Android Studio 1.3+ with NDK bundle.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/Teapot

Comment: Thanks for u r answer..but i have edit this question pls help me..